# Why is @mock.patch not mocking out my class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

So I am using `@mock.patch` in a unit test, but when I run the unit test, it is clearly not mocking out the class that I would like.

Here is my code:

```
@mock.patch('flop_turn_river_cards.TheFlop')
def test_is_board_paired_on_turn(self, mockTheFlop):
    amhot = AnalyseMyHandOnTurn()
    amhot.turn1 = [[10, 'S'], [10, 'C'],[7, 'C'], [2, 'S']]
    amhot.turn2 = [[10, 'S'], [10, 'C'],[7, 'C'], [2, 'S']]
    amhot.did_board_pair_on_turn1 = True
    amhot.did_board_pair_on_turn2 = True
    amhot.board_pair_top_card_turn1 = True
    amhot.board_pair_top_card_turn2 = True
    amhot.is_board_paired_on_turn()

    assert amhot.hand_ratings_turn1['board_paired'] == 6
    assert amhot.hand_ratings_turn2['board_paired'] == 6
```

When I set a breakpoint inside TheFlop class, or a function inside the class, I can see it is not mocked.

Is there a way for me to test that the path is correct? - I believe it is, and if so how can I mock out TheFlop class?

Comment: What makes you think the class is not mocked ?

Comment: When I set a breakpoint in one of the functions of that class, and I do print(self), if it was mocked I believe it should show a mocked object? But when I print it, it shows the class

Comment: What I mean is that when I print(self), I see this: <flop_turn_river_cards.TheFlop object at 0x10422a430>

Comment: And if the mocked worked, it should show a mocked object if I am not mistaken

Comment: I realised the issue.... I was initialising the class outside of the function... And so of course the mock isn't applied at that point.